# Finding values of constants by comparing co-efficients in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

$h - (2A) / t^3 - K/t^2 + b*C*e^{b*t} =\\ \, \, 3^{1/2}*B + 3*p*(A/t^2 + E/t + h*t + C*e^{b*t})- \\ \,\,3^{1/2}*(g + 1)*(A/t^2 + E/t + h*t + C*e^{b*t})^{3/2}$

How can I find the values of the constants h, `A`, `K`, `C` and `b`, in terms of `B`, `g`, `p` (Any one or 2 or all 3 of `B`, `g`, `p`) by comparing co-efficients, or otherwise method.

Comment: Please post cut-and-pastable code rather than HTML or images.

Comment: h - (2 A)/t^3 - K/t^2 + b *C* e^(b t) == 
 3^(1/2)*B + 3*p*(A/t^2 + E/t + h*t + C*e^(b*t)) - 
  3^(1/2)*(g + 1)*(A/t^2 + E/t + h*t + C*e^(b*t))^(3/2)

Comment: (1) You can edit your question  to put the code there. (2) Wolfram Language is case sensitive so `E` is the correct form for Euler's number (and `E/t` should be, say `e/t`, if that e was meant to be some unknown value). (3) Symbol names can be more that one letter, so `ht` is not at all the same thing as `h*t`.

Comment: h - (2 A)/t^3 - K/t^2 + b C e^(b t) == 3^(1/2)*B + 3*p*(A/t^2 + K/t + h*t + Ce^(bt)) - 3^(1/2)*(g + 1)*(A/t^2 + K/t + h*t + Ce^(bt))^(3/2) .     Here t is a variable. h is constant. How can I find the values of the constants h, A, K, C and b, in terms of B, g, p (Any one or 2 or all 3 of B, g, p) by comparing co-efficients, or otherwise method